# Unitary Matrix for Quantum Random Walk

Tags: qiskit, unitarity

I am re-working a project which aims to implement a very simple version of a quantum random walk.

It actually is a simplified binary random walk on a cyclic graph. The idea is depicted in the following graph ([source](https://www.educative.io/))

[image: sketch of qrw]

The idea is to implement this as a 3 qubit system where the first qubit describes a "quantum" coin-toss by being in super position and the other two qubits describe the state of the walker. Or in other words:

$$
|q_{\text{walker}}\rangle \otimes |q_{\text{coin}}\rangle
$$

So in order to implement the sketch in a circuit one defines an $8\times 8$ unitary matrix.

The project defines the unitary matrix as an $8\times 8$ zero matrix and then changing specific matrix elements to one as follows:

```
U_mat[0][2] = 1
U_mat[1][1] = 1
U_mat[2][4] = 1
U_mat[3][6] = 1
U_mat[4][3] = 1
U_mat[5][7] = 1
U_mat[6][0] = 1
U_mat[7][5] = 1
```

The final Circuit for one step would look like this if I am not mistaken:

```
     ┌───┐┌──────────┐┌─┐      
q_0: ┤ H ├┤0         ├┤M├──────
     └───┘│          │└╥┘┌─┐   
q_1: ─────┤1 Unitary ├─╫─┤M├───
          │          │ ║ └╥┘┌─┐
q_2: ─────┤2         ├─╫──╫─┤M├
          └──────────┘ ║  ║ └╥┘
c: 3/══════════════════╩══╩══╩═
                       0  1  2
```

I understand that if the matrix element `U[r][c]=1`, this means that state $c$ becomes state $r$ when the unitary matrix $U$ is applied to state $c$. However, when I try to read the matrix indices and compare them to the sketch, I struggle a lot.
Say for example `U[1][1]=1`:
This means for me that state $|001\rangle \to |001\rangle$ or in other words, if the coin is state $|1\rangle$, then the `q_walk_state` goes from $|00\rangle \to |00\rangle$. But obviously, that should not be the case since then; we have a state that does not change.

Or another example `U[2][4]=1`:
For me, this means $|100\rangle \to |010\rangle$. Or in other words, if the coin qubit has state $|0\rangle$, then `q_walk_state` goes from $|10\rangle \to |01\rangle$. But also this connection is not resembled in the sketch.

I am afraid I am misunderstanding something fundamental here, but I am not sure what it is.
I hope this is enough information to understand the problem I am having.